# How to create a file containing a set of entries from a larger file in UNIX?

Tags: unix, cygwin, fasta

I'm working with a large fasta file, and want to create a file containing only the entries for a specific genus. grep alone is not working for this as it only includes the line containing the genus name, and I also want to include the protein code.

I tried

```
grep -i genus file.fasta > genus.txt
```

This did work but created a file with only the first line of each data entry, thus not including the protein sequence. I also tried

```
grep -iC6 genus file.fasta > genus.txt
```

This did not work as not all the sequences are the same length. Appreciate any help. I'm using Cygwin if it makes any difference.

Comment: You have correctly tagged the question as _fasta_, because to answer it, you need to have knowledge of how a fasta-file looks like. However not everyone here  is doing protein sequences using fasta, and you would get more help, if you would also define in your question, how in general a line in `file.fasta` looks like.